# how to use regextract to find occurences of a number when it ends with a 2 after decimel point

Tags: google-sheets, regex, regexextract

my number set looks like this example
-360.132,
125,
140.0152,
-400.13,
i would like to be able to have an if statement for the numbers that end with a "2" after the decimel point. So i want to grab -360.132 and 140.0152 and ignore the others in the above numbers.  I know very little about regular expressions. I tried =ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(E3:E105,\d$2)) where column E contained my number set but get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` to get the values that match a regular expression, converting numbers to text strings with `trim()`, like this:

`=filter(E3:E105, regexmatch(trim(E3:E105), "\.\d*2$"))`

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).